# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/AnimRes.class

Tags: android, duplicates, android-library

I am not sure what this error means while building apk in android studio.

> **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/AnimRes.class**

I am using these dependencies :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile files('libs/MD5Simply.jar')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried some research but it didn t help for my situtation,

I think i should exclude something but i didn t get it how.

Comment: Delete the `android-support-v4.jar` file from `app/libs`. You don't need it

Comment: @cricket_007 oh what a miss ! u saved my day 
Thanks a lot ..i thought something hard to be

Comment: Welcome. You also don't need any line that starts with `compile files('libs` because `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` already does that. It says "compile all jar files in the `app/libs` directory"

Comment: Yeah correct thanks @cricket_007